# Creating a User registration service

Tags: sql, security, uwp

I am making a UWP app where users must make a one time use account that is used later to login to a website, and then it is deleted. I want To make it secure, so my question is, Is storing user credentials in a SQL database a secure way to have a login? (assumming that they are stored encrypted, and send encrypted by UWP app, and decrypted by website)

Also, is there a way for my UWP app to quickly check if a username has been taken without decoding the entire database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as your password entries in the database are encrypted using a decent one way algorithm, there should be no reason to worry about security.

As for your second question, I don't see why you have to decode the entire database if you are simply executing a find query for the username in question. If your usernames are encrypted, however, it seems that your only option is to compare its hash against all of the other usernames stored.

**Note: You should not be able to "decode the entire database." This means that a hacker could also decode said database. One way encryption algorithms only!**

Comment: Hashing, not encryption. Hashing is one way. Encryption is a reversible process

Comment: @Horkrine Technicality - No harm no foul ;). I actually read up about this after reading your comment and have found that others have made the same confusion as myself with the terms; thanks for the info.